# load test with visual studio doesn't increment the number of users

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, stress-testing

I configured a load test in visual studio with the following settings:

```
Load Pattern: Step
Initial User Count: 500
Maximum User Count: 1000
Step Duration (seconds): 300
Step Ramp Time (seconds): 0
Step User Count: 250
```

I need to start the test with 500 users, then increment to 750 users and finish with 1000 users.

So, in my inform, in the **Key Indicators** section, I expect to see:
Load users: 
min: 500
max: 1000
avg: 750

But really I see:
Load users: 
min: 500
max: 500
avg: 500

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For how long did the test run? The *"Step Duration (seconds): 300"* plus the other values means that for the first 5 minutes there will be 500 users, between 5 and 10 minutes there should be 750 users and after 10 minutes there should be 1000 users.

Comment: Is there any update to your question? Have you solved it? If yes then can you show the solution? If no then can you [edit] the question to add additional details?